# maintaining a plan table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

If `PLAN_TABLE` is created automatically post Oracle 9i, then why do I get

> "Table or view does not exists"

while trying to explain plan. I am using oracle 11.1. I am logged in with schema owner account.

Comment: `select * from ALL_synonyms where synonym_name = 'PLAN_TABLE'`  if you don't see any results, you don't have permissions to the table.  and even if you see results, if your schema or public isn't listed, you still don't have access.

Comment: See [**Why PLAN_TABLE does not exist**](http://lalitkumarb.com/tag/plan-table-does-not-exist/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do I get "Table or view does not exists" while trying to explain plan.

There are two possibilities:

- The `USER` you have logged in as, doesn't have the privilege on `PLAN_TABLE`.
- `PLAN_TABLE` actually doesn't exist.

If you could get point 1 fixed, then well and good.

If [**plan table doesn't exist**](http://lalitkumarb.com/tag/plan-table-does-not-exist/), then you could create your own `PLAN_TABLE` by executing the Oracle provided script `utlxplan.sql`(given that the user has the create table privilege):

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Automatic Storage Management options

SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlxplan.sql

Table created.

SQL> DESC PLAN_TABLE;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 STATEMENT_ID                                       VARCHAR2(30)
 PLAN_ID                                            NUMBER
 TIMESTAMP                                          DATE
 REMARKS                                            VARCHAR2(4000)
 OPERATION                                          VARCHAR2(30)
 OPTIONS                                            VARCHAR2(255)
 OBJECT_NODE                                        VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_OWNER                                       VARCHAR2(30)
 OBJECT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(30)
 OBJECT_ALIAS                                       VARCHAR2(65)
 OBJECT_INSTANCE                                    NUMBER(38)
 OBJECT_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(30)
 OPTIMIZER                                          VARCHAR2(255)
 SEARCH_COLUMNS                                     NUMBER
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
 PARENT_ID                                          NUMBER(38)
 DEPTH                                              NUMBER(38)
 POSITION                                           NUMBER(38)
 COST                                               NUMBER(38)
 CARDINALITY                                        NUMBER(38)
 BYTES                                              NUMBER(38)
 OTHER_TAG                                          VARCHAR2(255)
 PARTITION_START                                    VARCHAR2(255)
 PARTITION_STOP                                     VARCHAR2(255)
 PARTITION_ID                                       NUMBER(38)
 OTHER                                              LONG
 OTHER_XML                                          CLOB
 DISTRIBUTION                                       VARCHAR2(30)
 CPU_COST                                           NUMBER(38)
 IO_COST                                            NUMBER(38)
 TEMP_SPACE                                         NUMBER(38)
 ACCESS_PREDICATES                                  VARCHAR2(4000)
 FILTER_PREDICATES                                  VARCHAR2(4000)
 PROJECTION                                         VARCHAR2(4000)
 TIME                                               NUMBER(38)
 QBLOCK_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(30)
```

> If everything fails, talk to your DBA.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am aware of this script but have a doubt.will this work same as the plan_table in oracle? or I need to take care of additional things in my queries or parameters?

Comment: @Nitesh It is **the Oracle provided script** which creates the `PLAN_TABLE` when you install Oracle and create the database the first time, or whenever you want to create the PLAN_TABLE as a standard way in Oracle.